# Capture audio from microphone, encode and save to wav file

Tags: silverlight, audio, encoding, streaming, nspeex

I've already seen this **Silverlight** [sample](http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx) (from Andrej) on audio stream capturing from a microphone and then with possibility to save it to the wav file. It works ok.

But can anybody help me how to modify this [sample](http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Audio-recorder-Silverlight-4-sample.aspx) and build-in **[NSpeex](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/)** encoding with saving encoded audio file to local disk?

**Many thanks in advance!**

Matjaz